# Understanding multiple variable assignment on one line in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm not sure how to ask this question properly cause I'm trying to understand something I don't understand yet and therefore I don't know the right terminology to use, but I came across this code snippet in a YouTube tutorial regarding PIL [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8b0qR8wQDzE).

**Question**

Could somebody please explain what the last line means? I'm guessing it is a Python style of declaring variables I am not familiar with yet and I dont know what it is called so I can't look it up.

```
import Image

filename = "py.png"
image = Image.open(filename)
size = width, height = image.size
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried to break down the logic of the last line but it doesn't make sense to me:

```
# assign value of width to size variable?     
size = width 
# assign value of image.size to height variable?
height = image.size
```

The problems I see with this are:

- `width` is not defined.
- `image.size` represents the images dimensions ie `(512,512)` so that doesn't seem like it would be an appropriate value for `height`.

I'm sure this is very simple, I just don't get it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

I think I figured it out by running the following:

```
>>> size = width, height = 320, 240;
>>> size
(320, 240)
>>> width
320
>>> height
240
```

So essentially what the code in the original post is saying is:

```
>>> size = width, height = 512, 512;
>>> size
(512, 512)
>>> width
512
>>> height
512
```

Which means:

"The variable `size` is a tuple made of two values (`width` and `height`) and their values are `512` and `512` resp".

The mechanics of it haven't really sunk in yet, but good enough for now.

Comment: You need to read it backwards... the `,` is used to create tuples... - so `512, 512` creates a two element tuple which are unpacked in `width, height`, then `size` is assigned to the tuple `width, height`... In short, width and height contain the individual values, but by use of unpacking, they're also viewed as a tuple for the assignment on the left...