# Initialize variables in one line?

Tags: python

Is it possible do the following initializations in one line? As I am quite curious whether a shorter code is possible.

```
X = []
Y = []
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402646/python-initializing-multiple-lists-line

Comment: Also [Understanding multiple variable assignment on one line in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24587972), ["variable, variable =" syntax in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12923059)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can initialize them using [sequence unpacking](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (tuple unpacking in this case)

```
X, Y = [], []
```

because it's equivalent to

```
(X, Y) = ([], [])
```

You can also use a semicolon to join lines in your example:

```
X = []; Y = []
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use tuple unpacking (or multiple assignment):

```
X, Y = [], []
```